# Angular8 - Consuming JSON api response and pass to a jquery function

Tags: jquery, angular

I'm trying to receive a list of comments from an REST api and pass to the following **jquery** function. I realise this is **not the recommended way**, but its the only way I could get the jquery [library](https://github.com/Viima/jquery-comments) I'm using to work.

```
comments: Comment[] = [];

ngOnInit() {

$('#comments-container').comments({
  getComments: function(success, error) {
      //bad way (working)
      $.ajax({
          type: 'get',
          url: 'blah.blah/id/comment',
          success: function(commentsArray) {
              success(commentsArray)
          },
          error: error
      });
      //better way (not working)
      this.questionService.getComments().subscribe(res => {
        this.comments = res;
      })
      success(this.commentsArray) . //<--- need to pass response array here
  }
});
```

I have the service setup as follows;

```
export class QuestionService {

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

base_url = "https://blah.balh"

getComments() {
  return this.http.get(this.base_url+'/id/comment');
}
```

The error I'm getting with this code is;

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getComments' of undefined

I also tried an **observable** but couldn't get that to work, I tried various syntax but I got a map error

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context of `this` inside the `jquery` code is not same as inside the `Angular component`. The `this` inside the jquery code refers to the jquery only. In order to keep the context same, you need to bind the `context`.

Add `bind(this)` to your code. Modify you jquery code like this:

```
$('#id').function(<your jquery code>).bind(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a library that supports the features exposed by this lib but is Angular Compatible.

Meanwhile, you should call `success` inside the `subscribe` block:

```
comments: Comment[] = [];

ngOnInit() {
  $('#comments-container').comments({
    getComments: (success, error) => {
      this.questionService.getComments().subscribe(res => {
        this.comments = res;
        success(this.comments);
      })
    }
  });
}
```